# Sorting csv columns in bash, reading bash output into python variables

Tags: python, bash, shell

Hi I have a ton of data in multiple csv files and filter out a data set using grep:

```
user@machine:~/$ cat data.csv | grep -a "63[789]\...;"
637.05;1450.2
637.32;1448.7
637.60;1447.7
637.87;1451.5
638.14;1454.2
638.41;1448.6
638.69;1445.8
638.96;1440.0
639.23;1431.9
639.50;1428.8
639.77;1427.3
```

I want to figure out the data set which has the highest count, the column right of the ; and then know the corresponding value (left of the ;). In this case the set I'm looking for would be 638.14;1454.2

I tried different things and ended up using a combination of bash and python, which works, but isn't very pretty:

```
os.system('ls | grep csv > filelist')
files = open("filelist")
files = files.read()
files = files.split("\n")

for filename in files[0:-1]:
  os.system('cat ' + filename + ' | grep -a "63[6789]\...;" > filtered.csv')
  filtered = csv.reader(open('filtered.csv'), delimiter=';')
  sortedlist = sorted(filtered_file, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
  dataset = sortedlist[0][0] + ';' + sortedlist[0][1] + '\n'
```

I would love to have a bash only solution (cut, awk, arrays?!?) but couldn't figure it out. Also I don't like the work around writing the bash commands into files and then reading them into python variables. Can I read them into variables directly or are there better solutions to this problem? (probably perl etc... but I am really interested in a bash solution..)

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use Python, then use Python. Why are you intermixing bash commands together? It makes your code not portable/dependent on a bash environment.

```
import os
import glob
import operator
os.chdir("/mypath")
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    data=open(file).readlines()
    data=[i.strip().split(";") for i in data if i[:3] in ["637","638","639"]]
    # data=[i.strip().split(";") for i in data if i[:3] in ["637","638","639"] and isinstance(float(i[:6]),float) ]
    sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    print "Highest for file %s: %s" % (file,sortedlist[0])
```

OR, if you are more interested in a bash+tools solution

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' |while read -r FILE
do
 grep -a "63[789]\...;" "$FILE" | sort -n -r -t ';' -k 2 | head -1  >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: thanks that's a very nice script, but the filter for 637, 638 and 639 doesn't check the regexp \...; is that easily possible with python? what I just notice when running it are the "" around file in the data=open line.. thanks again I really like this snippet

Comment: If you really want to check using regex, you can use the `re` module. Otherwise, you can just simply check if its a float. see my edit.

Comment: +1, if you think you need frankenscripts, you probably don't know either of the environments (bash or python) well enough.  I'm often guilty of this.

Comment: does the find command have any advantage to a simple ls? like for i in $( ls *.csv ); do
    grep -a "63[789]\...;" $i | sort -r -n -t ';' -k2  | head -n 1
done

Comment: firstly, don't do `(ls *csv)`. This is called useless use of `ls`. Use shell expansion -> `for file in *csv`. Secondly, `find` and `ls` serve different purpose and `find` has a whole lot more features. `find` finds files recursively. a single `ls` do not , unless with `-R` flag

Answer (score 6):

A quick one-liner would be:

```
grep -a "63[789]\...;" data.csv | sort -n -r -t ';' -k 2 | head --lines=1
```

This simply sorts the file numerically based on the second column and then prints out the first row. Hope that helps.

Comment: Does the `-r `& `head` have added advantages over omitting `-r` & using `tail`?

Comment: If there was lots of data being piped between the two commands, it would be faster to read from the head then the tail.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat data.csv | grep -a "63[789]\...;" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"} $2>max{max=$2; val=$1} END {print "max " max " at " val}' 

max 1454.2 at 638.14
```

Comment: Thank you ars, this line works with the data displayed above, but I still need to filter out the dataset using grep "63[89]\...;", I tried piping it in, but it doesn't work. This line will not find a number on the csv because it contains a header etc ...

Comment: @gletscher: looks like you found a solution, but I've updated the answer to show how you'd pipe it to awk (which works on my end).

Comment: thanks so much for the update, it finds the correct location but doesn't display the result correctly, the output is:  at 638.14
also I am trying to loop over all the files in the directory and collect all the filtered data sets

Answer (score 1):

If you have *a ton of data* then you don't want to **store** all that data into memory and then **sort** it to get the max value. This approach is **inefficient** regarding both computing time complexity and memory.

You can simply parse the files and compute the desired values on-the-fly instead. A **fast** pure Python approach to deal with your problem:

```
import os, re
os.chdir('/path/to/csvdir')
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    dataset, count = 0.0, 0.0
    for line in open(f):
        if re.search(r'63[6789]\...', line):
            d, c = map(float, line.strip().split(';'))
            if count < c:
                dataset, count = d, c
    print f, dataset
```

This approach can also be used to show a list of max values (if there can be more than one dataset with highest counts) by modifying the appropriate lines:

```
dataset, count = [], 0.0
...
        if count < c:
            dataset, count = [d], c
        elif count == c:
            dataset.append(d)
```

**Edit:** the script assumes that your csvdir is populated only with files containing the parsing format. If you want to filter them by name, you can use either glob (with limited regexp capabilities in name filtering):

```
for f in glob.glob('*.csv'):
```

or apply a filter to `os.listdir`:

```
for f in filter(lambda f: re.match('.*\.csv', f), os.listdir('.')):
```

Comment: hey that's a super nice script, although the script runs into errors if other files are present in the folder, so using ghostdogs74 glob.glob("*.csv"): instead of os.listdir(".") seems to work better in this case, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is code I wrote to sort csv files using python. It allows you to specify multiple columns and to sort in reverse order by using a minus sign.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Usage:
# (1) sort ctb_consolidated_test_id.csv by Academic Year, Test ID, Period, and Test Name, with Test ID in descending order
#   sort_csv.py -c "Academic Year" -c "-Test ID" -c "Period" -c "Test Name" ctb_consolidated_test_id.csv
from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

def multikeysort(items, columns):
    from operator import itemgetter
    import re
    num_re = re.compile(r'^\d+$')
    comparers = [
        ((itemgetter(col[1:].strip()), -1) if col.startswith('-') else (itemgetter(col.strip()), 1))
        for col in columns
    ]
    def number_comparable(val1, val2):
        return len(val1) != len(val2) and num_re.match(val1) and num_re.match(val2)
    def column_comparer(left, right):
        for fn, mult in comparers:
            val1, val2 = fn(left), fn(right)
            if number_comparable(val1, val2):
                val1, val2 = int(val1), int(val2)
            result = cmp(val1, val2)
            if result:
                return mult * result
        return 0
    return sorted(items, cmp=column_comparer)

def sort_csv(filename, columns):
    import csv
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(reader.fieldnames, reader.fieldnames)))
        writer.writerows(multikeysort(reader, columns))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from glob import glob
    from optparse import OptionParser, make_option
    option_list = [
        make_option('-c', '--column', dest='columns', action='append', metavar='COLUMN NAME'),
    ]
    parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    filenames = (filename for arg in args for filename in glob(arg))
    for filename in filenames:
        sort_csv(filename, options.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

nice, thanks a lot, Hakop Palyan !!

Now is there a trick on how to get this data set out of all the csv files and collect it somewhere as a new file? something like

```
 find . -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -a "63[789]\...;" | sort -n -r -t ';' -k 2 | head --lines=1
```

this one prints only the first line, I would need to iterate over the individual files and collect the datasets ...

Comment: You should either ask this as a separate question or update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for a bash based solution but I could not help offering something using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) module.

```
import os
import csv
import re

target_re = re.compile(r'^63[789]\.\d\d$')
csv_filenames = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endwith('.csv')]
largest_in_each_file = []

for f in csv_filenames:
    largest = (None, 0)
    for a,b in csv.reader(open(f, 'rb'), delimiter=';'):
        if target_re.match(a) and b > largest[1]:
            largest = (a, b)
    largest_in_each_file.append(largest)


largest_overall = largest_in_each_file[0]
for largest in largest_in_each_file:
    print "%s;%s in %s" % largest
    if largest[1] > largest_overall[1]:
        largest_overall = largest

print "-" * 10
print "%s;%s in %s is the largest record in all files" % largest_overall
```